# Camera screen showing blank black

Tags: ios, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

I have a UIButton in my app name as "Add New Contact". When I click on this button It opens native new contact screen. but when I click on "add photo" in this native new contact screen, It have two option "Take Photo" and "Choose Photo". By clicking on "Take Photo", It opens camera but everything is showing **blank black** screen. Click option is also not working in this screen.
My code snippet is -

```
let con = CNContact()
        let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: con)
        vc.delegate = self
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please help me to fix this.
[image]

Comment: No, Its happening in iOS10. In iOS 11 "Take Photo" option is not showing, Only Choose Photo is coming in iOS 11

Comment: Camera option is already enabled for the app.

Comment: Did you tried with App_Delegate.window.rootViewController.present(....

Comment: Not working by doing App_Delegate.window.rootViewController.present

Comment: @iPatel - You can also check by creating a small demo. Its a major bug for me. I am stuck on this.

Comment: After googling I found so many question/discussion on this topic but no one can gives answer so might be it's bug not sure but you should put it as a bug on Apples bug report.